# Allow Remember Password to work with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passwords

Okay, I spent all morning trying to solve this, and despite the fact that it seems to have been a problem for a couple years, I couldn't find a solution that worked. I've seen other people on Stack Overflow ask this question, but none of them had working answers.

My Angular app's login form works fine, but the remember password dialog won't pop up in either Chrome or Opera. It does work in Firefox. I understand WHY it doesn't work, but my users are complaining and I need to fix it. What can I do?

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login(user)">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

Edit: 
Okay, from a couple different answers that didn't work, I was able to piece together something that finally did, which was simply to turn it into an entirely normal HTML form where the button is type="submit" and then simply put a jQuery .click command in my javascript which calls the login function. So basically, just completely ignored the Angular way of doing it, which makes me a sad panda. :-\ Opera still doesn't work, but I don't care a ton about that I guess.

Comment: Why does it not work in Chrome or Opera?

Comment: http://timothy.userapp.io/post/63412334209/form-autocomplete-and-remember-password-with

Comment: http://mukhanblogs.weebly.com/blogs/making-save-password-work-with-angular-js

Comment: Stafford, I'm not sure about Opera, although I assume it's the same. It's because Chrome looks for an HTML form to be submitted and Angular overrides the entire form process and doesn't actually submit a form.

Comment: I tried the mukhanblogs method before, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Okay, from a couple different answers that didn't work, I was able to piece together something that finally did, which was simply to turn it into an entirely normal HTML form where the button is type="submit" and then simply put a jQuery .click command in my javascript which calls the login function. So basically just completely ignored the Angular way of doing it. :-\

Opera still doesn't work, but I don't care a ton about that.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code from [Timothy E. Johansson's blog](http://timothy.userapp.io/post/63412334209/form-autocomplete-and-remember-password-with). I do not take credit.

```js
app.directive("ngLoginSubmit", function(){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        onSubmit: "=ngLoginSubmit"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element)[0].onsubmit = function() {
            $("#login-login").val($("#login", element).val());
            $("#login-password").val($("#password", element).val());

            scope.onSubmit(function() {
                $("#login-form")[0].submit();
            });
            return false;
        };
    }
};
});

$scope.login = function(submit) {
    $scope.user = {
        login: $("#login").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    function ajaxCallback() {
        submit();
    }   

    return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="" style="display: none;">
    <input name="login" id="login-login" type="text">
    <input name="password" id="login-password" type="password">
</form>

<form name="login-form" autocomplete="on" ng-login-submit="login">
    <input id="login" name="login" type="text" autocomplete="on">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="on">
</form>
```

Comment: I was hoping for an Angular solution that doesn't require jQuery. Seems weird to include all of jQuery in my app for this one small thing.

Though if this is what it takes, then so be it I guess. :-\

Comment: not my code :\  ... just a solution i came accross. posted it cos links break.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with AngularJS and without jQuery:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="on" id="email" ng-model="user.email">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="on" ng-model="user.password">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="login()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Explantion**

You should have `action` attribute in your `form` tag and a `button` with `type=submit` attribute. To prevent page from reloading, add `onsubmit="return false;"` to `form` tag. Simple :)